# python - svg enhancing the svg paths

Tags: python, svg

I have a svg generator from png, using Google compute engine for that combined with `vtracer` , was playing around with the [parameters](https://github.com/visioncortex/vtracer#cmd-app) , but the best result I can do is something like this:
[image: output svg zoomed in]

This is a piece of the result png, which is quite OK (using [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo) to optimize the paths), but I am not satisfied with particular shapes (red arrows on a picture above), I want them to be more simple, curved, smooth.

I was trying to write a python script for that, but still no success, the python code looks like this:

```
   import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys
from shapely.geometry import LineString

def detect_and_correct_artifacts(path_data, tolerance=1.5):
    path_commands = path_data.split()
    new_path_commands = [path_commands[0]]  # Start with the first command (M)

    i = 1
    while i < len(path_commands):
        if path_commands[i] in ['M', 'L', 'C', 'Q']:
            # Extract the coordinates for the current command
            coords = [float(path_commands[i + j]) for j in range(1, len(path_commands[i]))]

            # Check if the segment is continuous or non-continuous
            line = LineString([(coords[j], coords[j + 1]) for j in range(0, len(coords), 2)])
            if line.is_simple or line.length <= tolerance:
                new_path_commands.extend([path_commands[i]] + [f'{coords[j]} {coords[j + 1]}' for j in range(0, len(coords), 2)])
            else:
                new_path_commands.append(path_commands[i])
            
            i += len(coords) + 1  # Move to the next command
        else:
            new_path_commands.append(path_commands[i])
            i += 1

    return ' '.join(new_path_commands)

input_image = sys.argv[1]
output_image = sys.argv[2]

tree = ET.parse(input_image)
root = tree.getroot()

for path in root.findall('.//{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}path'):
    original_path_data = path.get('d')
    corrected_path_data = detect_and_correct_artifacts(original_path_data)
    path.set('d', corrected_path_data)

tree.write(output_image)
```

any suggestion of a library / code which may help me to improve the svg shapes? My goal is to create an automated script for that, not to use Adobe Illustrator or similar.

Any help/idea/input appreciated!